# Edited UV of low poly object but now high poly object wont show in UV tab (2.8 Beta)

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Using Blender 2.8 Beta.

I initially smart unwrapped my Cube_LO (low poly) object, but I did not like the normal bake from the UV, so I hid the Cube_HI (high poly) object, then manually marked seams of Cube_LO and unwrapped.

Next I baked the Normal map.

Finally I tried to compare again with the Cube_HI object by enabling visible, but now it won't show in the UV Editing tab.

Cube_HI was showing before I manually redid my UV unwraps.

See in the picture below that I only have Cube_HI visible, but it won't show anymore.

Cube_HI still shows in all the other tabs.

[image]

Also, I already tried restarting the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in Local mode. Press <kbd>/</kbd> on numpad.

[image]

Local mode temporary isolates selected objects for working with them.